# Data Visualization: Classifying chart types

Tags: resource-recommendations, dimensions, chart-design

I am trying to classify different chart types by the shape of their data, and I am looking for a helpful resource. For example, on a line chart, I am looking for a description like:

> A Line chart consists of three dimensions, of the following types:
>   Nominal, Ordinal, and Interval
>
> A Bar chart consists of two dimensions, of the following types....

Ideally, the dimensions would be classified using a system like [Levels of Measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levels_of_measurement)

Does anyone know if such a resource exists?

Answer (score 3):

Once I made a Keynote about **Graphs and Diagrams Classification**. Each graphic has an image example. This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLtg-jE2C9E&feature=youtu.be

[image: giagrams]

It's a five hours class, and each screen has its explanation, the video is only the representative part. It's in Spanish, but the classification is the next:

- Statistics
- Sequential
- Descriptive
- Location

And this is the sub-classification:

**Statistics**

- Area

  - Shape
  - Volume
  - Ring
  - Venn
- Bars

  - Horizontal
  - Vertical
  - Compound
  - Combined
  - Directional
- Curve

  - Simple
  - Multiple
- Matrix

**Sequential**

- Linear

  - Chronologies
  - Itineraries
  - Processes
  - Arches
- Flow

  - Hierarchical

    - Tree
    - Organigrams
  - Sankey
  - Time/activity
- Figurative

**Descriptive**

- Organizational

  - Table
  - Area
- Details

**Location**

- Plan

  - Geographical
  - Industrial
  - Architectural
- Maps

  - Cartographic
  - Astral

Answer (score 1):

[The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1930824130) by Edward Tufte:

> The classic book on statistical graphics, charts, tables. Theory and
>   practice in the design of data graphics, 250 illustrations of the best
>   (and a few of the worst) statistical graphics, with detailed analysis
>   of how to display data for precise, effective, quick analysis. Design
>   of the high-resolution displays, small multiples. Editing and
>   improving graphics. The data-ink ratio. Time-series, relational
>   graphics, data maps, multivariate designs. Detection of graphical
>   deception: design variation vs. data variation. Sources of deception.
>   Aesthetics and data graphical displays.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful, but can you summarize or provide a link to an answer here? I have read that book before, and I think it has the exact chart descriptions I am looking for, but is there a website that summarizes this information?